# How is a graph where every node is connected to every other node denoted?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, discrete-mathematics

How is a graph where every node is connected to every other node (without redundant connections) called?

I know that this graph has N * (N - 1) / 2 edges.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Complete Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)